# Python regex possibilities

Tags: python, regex, kodi

I have big json string, that i am trying to parse with python.
Basicly this string contains  iptv streams.

I am trying to develope addon for xmbc/kodi.

String example: http://pastebin.com/SmEGXaN9

I also need to split streams to 2 different ones: LIVE and VOD, **can i do this with regex ?**

In json LIVE streams have "live":"1" and VOD has "live":0"

I try to capture "live":"(.+?)" and then do if statement to see if its LIVE or VOD, but sometimes it doesnt return any "live":"1" for some reason.

**Is it possible to split streams up with regex instead of if statement?**

Here is function for LIVE grabbing:

```
def LIVE(url):
        xbmcplugin.addSortMethod( handle=int( sys.argv[ 1 ] ), sortMethod=xbmcplugin.SORT_METHOD_TITLE )
        vidlocation=('%s:%s/live/%s/%s/'%(site,port,usern,passw))
        link = OPEN_URL(url) #GET DATA FROM JSON API
        match=re.compile('{"name":"(.+?)","stream_id":"(.+?)","stream_icon":"(.+?)","live":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
        for name,streamid,iconimage,live in match:
           if "1" in live:
               addLink('%s'%(live),'%s%s.ts'%(vidlocation,streamid),'%s'%(iconimage).replace("\/","/"),'')
```

For LIVE streams i need to retrive 3 things: **name,stream_id,stream_icon**

Here is function for VOD grabbing:

```
def VOD(url):
        vidlocation=('%s:%s/movie/%s/%s/'%(site,port,usern,passw))
        link = OPEN_URL(url)
        match=re.compile('{"name":"(.+?)","stream_id":"(.+?)","live":"(.+?)","container_extension":"(.+?)","stream_icon":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
        for name,streamid,live,container,iconimage in match:
            if not "1" in live:
                addLink3('%s'%(name),'%s%s.%s'%(vidlocation,streamid,container),'','%s'%(iconimage).replace("\/","/"),'','PLOT')                
            else:
                #novod
```

For VOD streams i need to capture 4 things: **name,stream_id,container_extension;stream_icon**

Can someone help me build correct tregex for my need, and also please explain exactly what and how it does work. Python regex documentation is pretty complex for me.

Comment: I read the first line, and now I wonder why you don't use the built-in Python `json` module?

Comment: Echo above. Json is not a regular language. Strictly speaking it is not parsable with regex, not without assumptions on structure and depth, plus tons of complex logic. And complex logic doesn't make you cool.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i will go and try with json module. Sounds more reasonable.

Comment: Since your file size is about 220 Mo, I think it's a better idea to use `ijson` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson) instead of the json module. `ijson` is an event based parser, so your file is read as a stream and is not fully loaded in the memory.